# Assign values to char in java

Tags: java

I tried

```
int a = 100;
char c = a;  //doesn't work
```

but

```
char c = 100;  //does work
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence

```
char a = 100;
```

will work, as every number in char stands for symbol in Unicode, from 0 to 65,536

For example

```
char a = 435;
System.out.println("Output: " + a);
```

gives output

```
Output: Ƴ
```

As mentioned in answer below, type cast needed, when assigning `int` value to `char`, as `int` has wider values range (from -2147483648 to 2147483647) than `char`

For example,

```
long a = 1;
int b = a;
```

also impossible

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `char c = a;` does not work is since char and int are incompatible types.
***char can store 2 bytes*** where as ***int can store 4 bytes***. And so the java compiler does not allow the above operation since it can probably result in data loss while type conversion takes place.
To avoid the above issue, we can simply **typecast int to char** before assigning `char c = (char) a;`.

Comment: Yes, that's what's in the linked duplicate. There's no need to repeat that answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

compiler won't do '**Widening or Automatic Type Conversion**' for int to char.
[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/#:%7E:text=Java%20automatically%20promotes%20each%20byte,%2C%20float%2C%20or%20double%20respectively.)